How to set the type of the scan.partition.column field in the jdbc connector to datatime when the scan.partition.column field is datatime
Flink jdbc connectors, if the scan.partition.column field type is datatime, for example, "2024-04-28 00:00:00", how should the scan.partition.low-bound in Flink SQL be set? In the API documentation, scan. partition. power bond only supports the integer type.
